# First weekday on android phones

Tags: android, datetime

According to Androids documentation I get the impression, that Android only supports ISO 8601 week number calculation (this is good for me as I live in Austria).

So, I think that an "Android Week" alway starts on Monday. This is important for me, because I want to read/write Androids calendar and the recurrence rules are encoded with the rfc2445 standard. The field in question is "WKST"

> The WKST rule part specifies the day
>   on which the workweek starts.

As long my application is used in Europa there is no problem with assuming that Monday is the first day of week. But what about other countries (USA)?

Is my assumption correct?

References:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android supports Java's [`Calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek()). This will tell you the proper first day of the week in the current locale.

Please keep in mind that some people might want to have a different first day of the week from their locale.

Comment: Small problem is that android.text.format.Time set Monday as 1, but java Calendar class handle Monday as 2 :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford a bit larger apk, You might want to just bring in Joda Time. You can just add the .jar from the site into your project's build path.